# oracle sql ranking and count with conditional statements

Tags: sql, oracle, count, conditional-statements, row-number

I am stuck with the process of categorizing rows based on particular conditions. I am hoping to get through this with the support from you guys!
Basically, I am trying to create two new columns to the table by applying some particular formulas. Those columns are for ranking volume for each year and also for categorization by specifying whether each prac was included in the `top 3 claims` in `2014` or `not`. In the below examples, the columns highlighted in `light blue` are the ones I want to create.

[image]
My query is as below - right now I have a problem with writing codes for the two last lines above `from`, `group by` and `having` do not seem to work within those parentheses. Please help!!

```
select    
    fiscal_year,
    prac,
    count(*) "CLAIMS",
    sum(paid_amount) "COST",
    row_number() over (group by fiscal_year order by count(*) desc) "Annual Rank by Claims",
    case
        when row_number() over (having fiscal_year = '2014' order by count(*) desc) < 4
        then  'YES'
        else 'NO' 
    end "PRAC TOP 3 IN CLAIMS 2014"    
from mys.mv_claim
where category = 'V'
group by  fiscal_year,
    prac

/
```

Comment: Based on the columns in the picture, you want to create ranks within each year based on COST. Is that right?

Comment: Hi vashi,I want to create ranks within each year based on CLAIMS. thank you!

Comment: You have "DI", "FO" and "SN" each listed twice for the respective years. For "DI" and "FO" "PRAC TOP 3 IN CLAIMS 2014" is three times "YES" and another three times "NO". - How do you tell these apart?

Comment: Hi Abecee, sorry that was my mistake. I updated the example with different initials. Now that confusion should be gone.

Comment: What happens if two rows share the same claim count in a year, are they both rank X..

Comment: Hi Caius Jard, you are right. Their rank should be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen GROUP BY and HAVING used in a partitioning spec; I suspect it's a syntax error. I think your query needs to look more like:

```
WITH t as (
 select    
  fiscal_year,
  prac,
  count(*) "CLAIMS",
  sum(paid_amount) "COST"  
 from mys.mv_claim
 where category = 'V'
 group by  fiscal_year, prac
)
SELECT 
  t.*,
  rank() over (partition by fiscal_year order by claims desc) "Annual Rank by Claims",
  case
    when prac in(select prac from (select * from t where fiscal_year = 2014 order by claims desc ) where rownum <= 3)
    then  'YES'
    else 'NO' 
  end "PRAC TOP 3 IN CLAIMS 2014"
from t
```

I've used rank instead of row number, as two identical claim counts will produce a rank value the same. Rank will then skip the next rank (two 999 claim counts will each rank 1, a 998 claim count will rank 3. If you want it to rank 2 use dense_rank)

Let me know if you get any errors with this, as the only thing I'm not certain will work out is the subselect that retrieves the top 3 pracs. That can be done with a left join instead (which i have greater confidence in)

Answer (score 0):

Missing the original data, let the given (intermediate) output be the starting point - the first statement (resulting in **MV_Claim_Ranked**) could be replaced with your selection from **mys.mv_claim**:

```
WITH
MV_Claim_Ranked AS (
SELECT
    fiscal_year,
    prac,
    claims,
    cost,
    annual_rank_by_claim,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY fiscal_year ORDER BY claims DESC) annual_rank_by_claim_calc,
    prac_top_3_in_claims_2014
FROM MV_Claim_Grouped
)
SELECT
  T1.*,
  CASE WHEN (SELECT annual_rank_by_claim_calc
             FROM MV_Claim_Ranked T2
             WHERE T1.prac = T2.prac
               AND T2.fiscal_year = 2014) < 4
       THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS prac_top_3_in_claims_2014_calc
FROM MV_Claim_Ranked T1
ORDER BY prac, fiscal_year
;
```

Your aggregates are kept for reference.

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ab87/1).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.